# Attaching bespoke files to bespoke emails from a list in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, email-attachments

I am new to coding and have been trying to attach individual files from my desktop to the individual emails created by my current macro. the file names are saved on a sheet in the active WB that have the names and emails of my recipients in. i want to match the file name with the appropriate recipient and attach the file to my email for that recipient.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

I have tried adding some solutions i found online but still unable to figure it out.

```vb
Sub SendEmailfromOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Path As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In Range("B2:B123")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
              With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Datalocker User Check"
                .Body = "Hello " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," _
                      & vbNewLine & "** Requires Response **" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "If you have received this email it is because we are doing a user check on datalocker secure file transfer." & vbCr & _
                      "Attached you will see a spreadsheet that shows all active users currently at your organisation." & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "Normally we would request a form in order to make amendments but in this instance and for every new school term we will make all amendments that you need if you respond to this email" & vbCr & _
                      "I have attached a file for reference to roles and the functions they have." & vbCr & _
                      "Any new user that needs adding please fill their details in at the bottom of the table and we will add them as soon as we can." & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "Can you also answer the following questions, these are being asked so we can update our records of these two roles in your school since there has been changes to staff in these roles that we haven't updated." & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "Who is the current Headteacher and what is their email?" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "Who is the current Business/Office Manager and what is their email" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "Kind Regards" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                      "" & vbCr & _
                      "" & vbCr & _
                      "" & vbCr & _
                      "" & vbCr & _
                      ""
                .Save
            End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: [Attachments.Add method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add)

Comment: So in your case, in the `With OutMail`, add `.Attachments.Add cell.offset(0,1).value` (assuming path in column C)